# Why mounting readonly dmg sometimes changes image file

Tags: macos, dmg-image

Why some readonly dmg images are changing when mounted and what is changed in them? I mean readonly image, not readonly or locked dmg file.

Answer (score 3):

Generally most .dmg files are compressed or otherwise read-only - Mac OS X should not allow any changes to these. Certain types of .dmg images however are mounted read-write (sparseimage comes to mind). If you have write permission to the image, Finder has a really bad habit of populating every folder with metadata (.DS_Store, etc. - *very* irritating to find 50mb of these files on a flash drive). Viewing, or perhaps simply mounting will trigger Finder to begin indexing and creating these files, leading to a modified image even if you have not added any files yourself.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not very accurate. I was wondering why are readonly dmg files changing when mounted (not readonly file, but readonly image), I edited question. My bad :)